# expand dataset using dplyr complete to incorporate 0's

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where animals were sampled at different sites in different years.  The age class of the animals was recorded as well as the proportion of females and number of males.

I need to expand the dataset to include the 0 values in years when the site was surveyed, but no individuals from that age class were recorded.  A subset of the data is in the present form:

```
df <- structure(list(
  site = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                   levels = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
  year = c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2002, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
           2008, 2009, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
           2010, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2005), 
  age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                  levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
  propF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 
            0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.9, 1, 1), 
  nM = c(48L, 30L, 41L, 30L, 22L, 23L, 81L, 29L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 23L, 14L, 
         43L, 42L, 29L, 30L, 72L, 88L, 83L, 17L, 65L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
print(df, n=30)
# A tibble: 29 × 5
   site   year age   propF    nM
   <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <int>
 1 B      2002 1       0      48
 2 B      2003 1       0      30
 3 B      2004 1       0      41
 4 B      2005 1       0      30
 5 B      2006 1       0      22
 6 B      2007 1       0.1    23
 7 B      2008 1       0      81
 8 B      2009 1       0      29
 9 B      2002 2       0.2     4
10 B      2005 2       0.5     1
11 B      2006 2       1       0
12 B      2007 2       0.8     3
13 B      2008 2       0.8     1
14 B      2009 2       0.8     3
15 A      2000 1       0      23
16 A      2001 1       0.2    14
17 A      2002 1       0.2    43
18 A      2003 1       0.1    42
19 A      2004 1       0.3    29
20 A      2005 1       0.2    30
21 A      2006 1       0.1    72
22 A      2007 1       0.1    88
23 A      2008 1       0.1    83
24 A      2009 1       0.1    17
25 A      2010 1       0.1    65
26 A      2000 2       1       0
27 A      2001 2       0.9     1
28 A      2003 2       1       0
29 A      2005 2       1       0
```

Site A was surveyed from 2000-2010, but individuals of age class 2 were only observed in 4/11 years.  I need put 0's in the propF and nM columns for years when no individuals of that age class were observed.  But I need to do it in a way that doesn't change the range of years of Site B (surveyed 2002-2009). (NOTE: in the real dataset, there are many sites that were surveyed over different windows).

The closest I've gotten is with the following code, however, it adds years for site B outside so that the timeseries matches site A.

```
df %>% complete(year, 
                nesting(site, age),
                fill = list(propF = 0))
```

EDIT: Expected output for site A would look like the following (no changes to site B):

```
15 A      2000 1       0      23
16 A      2001 1       0.2    14
17 A      2002 1       0.2    43
18 A      2003 1       0.1    42
19 A      2004 1       0.3    29
20 A      2005 1       0.2    30
21 A      2006 1       0.1    72
22 A      2007 1       0.1    88
23 A      2008 1       0.1    83
24 A      2009 1       0.1    17
25 A      2010 1       0.1    65
26 A      2000 2       1       0
27 A      2001 2       0.9     1
28 A      2003 2       0       0*
29 A      2003 2       1       0
30 A      2004 2       0       0*
31 A      2005 2       1       0
32 A      2006 2       0       0*
33 A      2007 2       0       0*
34 A      2008 2       0       0*
35 A      2009 2       0       0*
35 A      2010 2       0       0*
```

*indicate the 0's that have been added.

Comment: Could you clarify how your expected output looks like?

Comment: @MartinGal I've updated the question to show what would happen for Site A.

Comment: Why don't you group by site (and remove it from `nesting()`)?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I don't see any changes in my df, if I try the following:

df %>% complete(site, fill = list(propF = 0)

Comment: You misunderstood - try `df %>% group_by(site) %>% complete(year, age, fill = list(propF = 0, nM = 0))`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I think this solves the question of @tnt. One small hint: to quickly check visually that the range of years is correct per `site` and `age`, you can append `group_by(site,age) %>% group_split()` at the end (personal preference, but maybe you also find it useful)

Comment: @RitchieSacramento ah! yes, that works.  If you want to write up an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided in the comments above by Ritchie Sacramento.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(site) %>% 
   complete(year, age,
            fill = list(propF = 0, nM = 0))
```

This fills in the 0's without expanding the range of monitoring dates outside of what there is already data for at each site.